# Keyboard and touchpad getting stuck all of sudden

Tags: linux-mint, xorg, touchpad, xfce4

I am using Xfce 4.12 and my keyboard and touchpad tapping and right click on touchpad gets stuck all of sudden but the left button on the touchpad is OK.

After I logout and login again the problem disappears.

I tried plugging in a USB mouse to check if the problem is specific to my laptop keyboard and touchpad. But, even when I plugin the mouse, the mouse is able to move, but the right click did not work. Only the left click worked.
**So, there seems not to be any problem with the hardware.**

This happened several times. I have gone through /var/log/Xorg.0.log file and also the Xorg.0.log.old file and also possible through the kernel log file. **But I didn't find any errors there.**

I am using Dell Inspiron laptop. In Xorg.0.log file, there is an input device called Dell WMI Hotkeys. I suspect if there is some problem with it.

I am using Linux Mint 18 Xfce.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. The ribbon connector from the keyboard/pad is likely loose. Easy fix once reseated.

Comment: I can understand that a loose connector can cause an intermittent problem — but a problem that always disappears when the user logs out and logs in again, and never disappears at a random time?  It seems unlikely that this is the OP's problem.